# Different login in each module YII

Tags: php, yii

I have ***2 module*** with 1 users tabel for login and i use ***extension right*** for manage access privilage of both module, i want if user has loged in frist module user cant direct open second module, user must login frist to second module too, otherwise

thanks before, and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score -2):

The user session can be accessed by all modules, so yes this is possible.

To test this out, login on module 1 (or main app).

Write the following code somewhere in module 2:

```
if (!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) {
  echo 'You are logged in!';
}
```

Comment: i know it but how to make when user has loged in frist module user CANT direct access second module, user must login frist to second module too, otherwise

Comment: Logout the current user when it's going to module 2 and when the user logs in on module 2, set a session variable so you know it's logged in from module 2? You can do this in your modules/xxx/xxxModule.php file. Create a beforeControllerAction() method (function) and there you can put in logic you need to run before the controller/action is executed.